# How to solve undefined method in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

First, sorry for my english,

I'm make a forum from scratch and I'm currently having an issue when I generate the post form

```
Showing D:/Lab/Rails/Forum/app/views/forumposts/_form.html.erb    
undefined method `forumposts' for nil:NilClass
```

Model forumtopic.rb

```
belongs_to :forumforum
has_many  :forumposts, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :user
```

Model forumpost.rb

```
belongs_to :forumtopic
belongs_to :user
```

forumposts_controller.rb

```
def create
  @topic = Forumtopic.friendly.find(params[:forumtopic_id])
  @forumpost = @topic.forumposts.create(params.require('forumpost').permit(:content))
   if @forumpost.save
      redirect_to forumtopic_path(@topic)
    else
      render 'new'
   end
end
```

Views/forumposts/_form.html.erb

```
<% if signed_in? %>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="post_form">
  <%= simple_form_for([@topic, @topic.forumposts.build]) do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: "post-textarea", placeholder: "Message", cols: 50, rows: 4 %>
    </div>
    <div>
     <%= f.submit "Save ", class: "post-button" %>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

views/forumtopics/show.html.erb

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="answer"> <%= @forum_topic.forumposts.count %> answers </div> **OK**
  </div>
</div>

 <%= render @forum_topic.forumposts %> **OK**

 <% render 'forumposts/form' %> **Problem**
```

When I do that in console, I get all the topic's post:

```
@topic = Forumtopic.first
@topic.forumposts
```

Please help

thank you

Comment: Undefined method for NilClass means you don't have a topic. Are you sure you have a forumTopic for that id? Run Forumtopic.friendly.find(params[:forumtopic_id]) in a rails console to see if it exists.

Comment: irb(main):003:0> Forumtopic.friendly.find("placer-un-menu")

Comment: Forumtopic Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "forumtopics".* FROM "forumtopics" WHERE "forumtopics"."slug" = ? LIMIT ?  [["slug", "placer-un-menu"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Forumtopic id: 1, subject: "Placer un menu", description: "\r\nBonsoir,\r\nJe rencontre un soucis au niveau d'un ...", forumforum_id: 1, user_id: 4, slug: "placer-un-menu", locked: false, resolved: false, created_at: "2016-12-26 13:56:25", updated_at: "2016-12-26 13:56:25">

Comment: Same result with:  irb(main):002:0> Forumtopic.friendly.find(1)

Comment: I think it's an id problem, I am looking for the solution, thank you for the indication.

Answer (score 0):

In `forumposts_controller.rb` you should have action `new` with tne next code:

```
def new
  @topic = Forumtopic.friendly.find(params[:forumtopic_id])
end
```